# Copy file from local machine to remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, server, rsync, scp

I have a pretty novice question, but I'm really out of resources right now.

I'm trying to send a script to a remote machine. This script is in my local machine and it's called model.py.

I can access the remote machine by typing `ssh csousa@headtop.ncc.unesp.br` (the remote machine knows my public key)

I read about the usage of the scp and rsync commands. I tried:

```
rsync -v -e ssh /home/ecaue/ParticlePhysics/TCC/model.py csousa@headtop.ncc.unesp.br
```

and

```
    scp -r csousa@headtop.ncc.unesp.br /home/ecaue/ParticlePhysics/TCC/model.py
```

but what I get is just a copy of my original file with another name ("csousa@headtop.ncc.unesp.br") in the same folder of my original file (like a clone with a different name).

I can access the remote machine and create conda environments and all kind of stuff(install tensorflow, keras,etc), but I'm not able to send my scrip and my dataset.

I would really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

The scp command should be:

```
scp PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT/SCRIPT_NAME user@host:DESTINATION_PATH
```

So in you case:

scp /home/ecaue/ParticlePhysics/TCC/model.py csousa@headtop.ncc.unesp.br:$HOME

Comment: No need for $HOME.  Just put `:` on the end.

Comment: Is to show that you can specify each path u want after the ended colon